# What does |= means in C?

Tags: c, gcc

I am reading source code of NCURSES and found in function the following thing:

```
unsigned long attrs = (1UL - 1UL);   //Setting to zero
```

but what do the following line do:

```
attrs |= ((1UL) << ((14) + 8));
printf("%d \n", attrs);
attrs |= ((1UL) << ((11) + 8));
printf("%d \n", attrs);
```

and when I output the result it has given the answer Output:

```
4194304
4718592
```

Comment: This is written in operators chapter of every C book

Comment: note: `>>=`,  `<<=`, `&=`, `^=` are also valid operators in C

Comment: `unsigned long attrs` declares `attrs` as a variable of type `unsigned long`, guaranteed to be at least 32 bits. `= (1UL - 1UL)` initializes it to zero, in a _stupid_ convoluted way. `attrs |= ((1UL) << ((14) + 8);` does a binary (bitwise) shift of `1UL` (1, as an unsigned long) 22 bits leftward, does a bitwise OR operation of that value against the value stored in `attrs`, and stores the result back into `attrs`. Effectively, this "turns on" one bit in the value stored in `attrs`.

Comment: `printf("%d \n", attrs);`, however, passes an `unsigned long` to `printf()`, and _lies to printf_, saying "here's a `signed int`, please print it for me". This is Undefined Behavior, and is almost certainly a bug.

Answer (score 12):

It is an *in-place bitwise OR*. `x |= y` is mostly equivalent to writing `x = x | y`, except that the LHS isn't evaluated twice.

It is normally used to add bitflags to a variable:

```
flags |= FLAG_X; // add flag x
flags |= FLAG_Y; // add flag y
flags &= ~FLAG_Z; // remove flag z
```

Answer (score 6):

This operator(the bitwise OR operator in C) helps in [Bit masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

`attrs |= ((1UL) << ((14) + 8));`

Or, equivalently, you could set it like this:

`attrs = attrs | ((1UL) << ((14) + 8));`

Comment: please explain downvote

Comment: I was also down-voted :( , may be because people think its silly question! but some time this question appreciated very much..just random behavior, and (for someone `|=` may not != to `|` because `|=` is bit faster)

Answer (score 5):

It is a shorthand notation for..

```
attrs = attrs | ((1UL) << ((14) + 8));
```

Comment: @vidit You both get a +1 from me anyway :)

Comment: With the exception of `attrs` evaluating twice.

Answer (score 4):

It's just a short-hand for :

```
attrs = attrs | ((1UL) << ((14) + 8));
```

Comment: Ghost downvoter, feel free to explain us our faults.

Comment: Don't worry I always upvote against the ghosts because I have also been a victim of it :) .....lol :)

Answer (score 3):

That's the bitwise-or assignment operator.  In your case it's pretty much equivalent to:

```
attrs = attrs | ((1UL) << ((14) + 8));
```